# Why I can not install an application on android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem. I generated an app on Android Studio, but when I move the application.apk to my phone. This message on the photo appears . But when I click on Install, nothing happens. How can I solve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjuJv.png)

[image]

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with your phone than with Android Studio. Maybe try [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: what does that error translate to in english?

Comment: Its not an error, its a message when you will install an app. When I click in Install, not happens, when I click in Cancel, it cancels the program

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall this application . and install again .

If you've compiled the program on another computer first. It happens . This problem arises from the signing of the developer.

> Go to File > Project Structure > select project > go to "signing"

Or you can find this path:

> C:\User\YourUser.android\debug.keystore

You can copy compiled keystore to new computer and test .